# How to populate a List<T> from a source string separated by commas and newlines

Tags: c#, list

I've got a string

```
string strsource = "0,0,200,0,206,2,28515663\r\n0,0,200,0,206,2,2029\r\n0,0,200,1,8,2,2039\r\n0,0,200,1,12,2,2039\r\n0,0,200,2,8,2,2039\r\n0,0,200,2,12,2,2039\r\n0,0,200,3,8,2,2040\r\n0,0,200,3,12,2,2040\r\n";
```

and a class with properties

```
public class justme
{
    public string field1 {get; set; }
    public string field2 {get; set; }
    public string field3 {get; set; }
    public string field4 {get; set; }
    public string field5 {get; set; }
    public string field6 {get; set; }
    public string field7 {get; set; }
}
```

What is the best way to populate a `List<justme>` knowing that the field on the source is separated by commas and new items on the list by `\r\n`

Comment: Can you show your attempts? All you have to do is, as you say, split on these two delimiters.

Comment: split at "\r\n", then split those results by ',' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx   try it ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? For example, do you want the simplest way, the way most resilient to invalid data, the way that is easiest to modify if requirements change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split, loop, split, assign:

```
List<justme> justmes = new List<justme>();
foreach(var line in Regex.Split(strsource, "\r\n")) {
  string[] fields = line.Split(',');

  justmes.Add(new justme {
    field1 = fields[0];
    field2 = fields[1];
    // field3 = ...
    // etc...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be one good way to put it.

```
var lines = strsource.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
.Where(line => line != string.Empty)
.Select(line =>
{
    var cols = line.Split(',');

    var me = new justme();
    {
        me.field1 = cols[0];
        me.field2 = cols[1];
        me.field3 = cols[2];
        me.field4 = cols[3];
        me.field5 = cols[4];
        me.field6 = cols[5];
        me.field7 = cols[6];
    }

    return me;
}).ToArray();
```